# Pass-through pixel shader not displaying properly

Tags: xna, c#, shaders, hlsl, monogame

I'm new to shaders, HLSL and XNA in general. I'm trying to write a pass-through pixel shader but I'm experiencing some odd behaviour. I created a simple texture, shown below:

[image: 1]

Here's what I see when I run my game:

[image: 2]

Drawing the texture without passing `effect` in `spriteBatch.Begin()` works fine, for instance:

[image: 3]

Drawing the texture at (40, 10) instead of (0, 0) gives different results, too (the green stripe isn't as thick):

[image: 4]

My shader file:

```
sampler input;

float4 PixelShaderFunction(float2 coords: TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{
    float4 color = tex2D(input, coords);
    return color;
}

technique Technique1
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        PixelShader = compile ps_4_0_level_9_1 PixelShaderFunction();
    }
}
```

My game code:

```
public class Game1 : Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Texture2D tex;
    Effect effect;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        tex = Content.Load<Texture2D>("tex");
        effect = Content.Load<Effect>("effect");
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            Exit();

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin(sortMode: SpriteSortMode.Immediate, effect: effect);
        spriteBatch.Draw(tex, new Vector2(0, 0), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm expecting my pass-through shader to simply draw the texture on the screen as-is (appearing as in the second screenshot above), but it looks totally wrong. (For what it's worth, I was trying to follow this tutorial: http://blog.josack.com/2011/07/my-first-2d-pixel-shaders-part-1.html)

Comment: Are you using the screen coordinates as texture coordinates? (I don't speak HLSL, but that's what it looks like from your screenshots)

Answer (score 1):

Since you override SpriteBatch's default effect with your own, you are now responsible for setting effect parameters, especially matrices. You probably would like to replicate default SpriteBatch behaviour, so set `effect.World` to identity, and for projection default SpriteBatch effect uses
`effect.Projection = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0) * Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height, 0, 0, 1);`